# How could I move existing wordpress to kubernetes?

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm about to move my existing wordpress website to kubernetes. I've created helm chart with everything such as pvc, configmap, ingress, deployment and so on. But main problem is how could I move existing wordpress content folder to PVC? I mean, could I move wordpress content folder from my laptop to PVC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would approach this problem first by creating a docker image of your wordpress website. This tutorial might help https://buddy.works/guides/wordpress-docker-kubernetes-part-1 .

Then I can push this new image to docker hub. And then I would not need PVC but a Deployment kubernets object that instantiate this image.

After you have a PVC in your k8s you can use a mountPath in pod, as it is shown here https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-volume-storage/ .

Comment: No, it's not workable solution. Even I could create docker image, I need to mount exiting wordpress content. The thing is how could I move existing wordpress content to kubernetes volume.

Comment: After you have an image/or not if you will, you can mount a dir into your pod. I put the link on the answer